# Disable HTC Gesture Options

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a HTC One X.
I can disable it from settings -> Select Display & gestures -> Uncheck "HTC Gestures".

But How can I disable the Gesture option programmatically?

Comment: You can only disable it if HTC provide API's for it. It's not native to Android.

Comment: I understand. But is there any workaround ?

Comment: Sign up for the *HTC OpenSense SDK* and see if they've added APIs for it.